# Unescape double backslash sequences in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, unicode-escapes

I have a string like this:

```
'hello this is nice\\r\\n\\xc2\\xa0 goodbye'
```

I need to convert this into plain utf-8 text.

The codecs library did not solve this:

```
codecs.unicode_escape_decode(x)[0]
'hello this is nice\r\nÂ\xa0 goodbye'
```

How do I turn that string into clean utf-8 text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not particularly elegant, but this seems to do what you are asking.

```py
>>> codecs.unicode_escape_decode(x)[0].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'hello this is nice\r\n\xa0 goodbye'
```

Slightly obscurely, the Latin-1 encoding has the attractive property that every byte encodes exactly that character code, so it can be used to transparently convert `bytes` to string or vice versa.

(In case it's not obvious, `b'\xc2\xa0'` is the UTF-8 encoding of [U+00A0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "for real".  The single quotes are how the Python REPL represents a string which begins with the characters `h`, `e`, `l`, `l` and has a carriage return character (0x13) and a newline (0x10) and a Unicode non-breaking space (`\u00a0`) around the middle.

Comment: @mobiusinversion escapes are for visual debugging.  How else do you "see" various forms of whitespace?  `print` the string to see its rendered value.